# Is there a way I can add title and labels to subplots generated?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a diurnal curve, which would give 12 subplots, each for different months.
Is there a way to label the axes of each subplot and give a title like 'Monthly concentration' to each subplot?

I've attached an output snapshot as well.

I am putting in a sample data frame for the sake of the code-

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as d
import numpy as np
dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = ['From Date',   'NO',          'NO2',       'NOx',    'CO',           'Ozone'],           
    data = [
        ['2018-12-30 00:00:00', 5.856666,    39.208341,   28.97,   331.280881,  19.778900],
        ['2018-12-30 01:00:00', 4.050059,    16.262145,   13.53,   454.031703,  25.075286],
        ['2018-12-30 02:00:00', 4.057806,    15.293990,   12.96,   466.502681,  24.825294],
        ['2018-12-30 03:00:00', 3.835476,    13.526193,   11.71,   446.526784,  25.033312],
        ['2018-12-30 04:00:00', 4.230690,    11.251531,   10.70,   355.638469,  25.748796],
        ['2020-01-01 05:00:00',    1,            2,        6.91,    4,             5],
['2020-01-01 06:00:00',            5,           10,        7.37,    13.2,          9],
['2020-01-01 07:00:00',            4,           13,        8.28,    4,             4],
['2020-01-01 08:00:00',            3,           9,         8.57,    3,             5],
['2020-01-01 09:00:00',            2,           4,         9.12,    4,             6]
    ]
)
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('From Date')
dataframe.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
dataframe['NOx']=dataframe['NOx'].astype(float)
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
# Get the Unique Months
months = dataframe['Month'].unique()
# Creates subplots based on the number of months
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(months),figsize=(10, 50))

# Iterate over axes and months together
for month, ax in zip(months, axes):
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label=month)
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['75%'], color='g')
    ax.plot(df.index, df["NOx"]['25%'], color='r')
    ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NOx"]['mean'], df["NOx"]['75%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='g')
    ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NOx"]['mean'], df["NOx"]['25%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='r')
    ax.legend()
    ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
```

[Plots obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBT5N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as d
import numpy as np
dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = ['From Date',   'NO',          'NO2',       'NOx',    'CO',           'Ozone'],           
    data = [
        ['2018-12-30 00:00:00', 5.856666,    39.208341,   28.97,   331.280881,  19.778900],
        ['2018-12-30 01:00:00', 4.050059,    16.262145,   13.53,   454.031703,  25.075286],
        ['2018-12-30 02:00:00', 4.057806,    15.293990,   12.96,   466.502681,  24.825294],
        ['2018-12-30 03:00:00', 3.835476,    13.526193,   11.71,   446.526784,  25.033312],
        ['2018-12-30 04:00:00', 4.230690,    11.251531,   10.70,   355.638469,  25.748796],
        ['2020-01-01 05:00:00',    1,            2,        6.91,    4,             5],
['2020-01-01 06:00:00',            5,           10,        7.37,    13.2,          9],
['2020-01-01 07:00:00',            4,           13,        8.28,    4,             4],
['2020-01-01 08:00:00',            3,           9,         8.57,    3,             5],
['2020-01-01 09:00:00',            2,           4,         9.12,    4,             6]
    ]
)
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('From Date')
dataframe.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
dataframe['NOx']=dataframe['NOx'].astype(float)
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
# Get the Unique Months
months = dataframe['Month'].unique()
# Creates subplots based on the number of months
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(months),figsize=(10, 50))
fig.suptitle("fig.suptitle")  # <--------------

# Iterate over axes and months together
for month, ax in zip(months, axes):
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label=month)
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['75%'], color='g')
    ax.plot(df.index, df["NOx"]['25%'], color='r')
    ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NOx"]['mean'], df["NOx"]['75%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='g')
    ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NOx"]['mean'], df["NOx"]['25%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='r')
    ax.legend()
    ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
    ax.set_title("ax.set_title")  # <--------------
    ax.set_xlabel("ax.set_xlabel")  # <--------------
    ax.set_ylabel("ax.set_ylabel")  # <--------------
```

[image]

Read this: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the following to your loop:

```
ax.set_xlabel('common xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('common ylabel')
ax.set_title('ax title')
```

You can refer to the following link for more info:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, I am Iterated `titles` and `labels`. So, that you are able to give every graph a different title and label.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = ['From Date',   'NO',          'NO2',       'NOx',    'CO',           'Ozone'],           
    data = [
        ['2018-12-30 00:00:00', 5.856666,    39.208341,   28.97,   331.280881,  19.778900],
        ['2018-12-30 01:00:00', 4.050059,    16.262145,   13.53,   454.031703,  25.075286],
        ['2018-12-30 02:00:00', 4.057806,    15.293990,   12.96,   466.502681,  24.825294],
        ['2018-12-30 03:00:00', 3.835476,    13.526193,   11.71,   446.526784,  25.033312],
        ['2018-12-30 04:00:00', 4.230690,    11.251531,   10.70,   355.638469,  25.748796],
        ['2020-01-01 05:00:00',    1,            2,        6.91,    4,             5],
['2020-01-01 06:00:00',            5,           10,        7.37,    13.2,          9],
['2020-01-01 07:00:00',            4,           13,        8.28,    4,             4],
['2020-01-01 08:00:00',            3,           9,         8.57,    3,             5],
['2020-01-01 09:00:00',            2,           4,         9.12,    4,             6]
    ]
)
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('From Date')
dataframe.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
dataframe['NOx']=dataframe['NOx'].astype(float)
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
# Get the Unique Months
months = dataframe['Month'].unique()
# Creates subplots based on the number of months
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(months),figsize=(10, 50))

#List of titles, xlabels, ylabels
titles = ['First Plot', 'Second Plot']
xlabels = ['xlabel 1', 'xlabel 2']
ylabels = ['ylabel 1', 'ylabel 2']
#Initialization
x=0


# Iterate over axes and months together
for month, ax in zip(months, axes):
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label=month)
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['75%'], color='g')
    ax.plot(df.index, df["NOx"]['25%'], color='r')
    ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NOx"]['mean'], df["NOx"]['75%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='g')
    ax.fill_between(df.index, df["NOx"]['mean'], df["NOx"]['25%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='r')
    ax.legend()
    ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    
    #Displays titles as increments x
    ax.title.set_text(titles[x])
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabels[x])
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabels[x])
    x=x+1
    

    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
```